# Block-chain memorised 5.000.000 of hash

Tags: ethereum, algorand

I have 5.000.000 of hash that I have to memorised in a Block-chain plus on the future others, at beginning I have thought to use Ethereum using proxy pattern but I have seen that the cost is too much expansive. So I start to think to use Algorand.

But my questions are:

- is it right?
- a single transactions in Ethereum is less than Algorand even on the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, algorand is very cost efficient because it uses PPOS mechanism. It is consensus mechanism where with verifiable random function system reduce the load on the verification.

Because the resource cost, the algorand will be much cheaper to run in the future even than the delegated proof of stake consensus mechanisms..